Reference for the embedding $\mathfrak{so}(mn)\supset \mathfrak{so}(m)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(n)$ and its projection matrix
I am trying to understand the special embedding of the Lie algebra:
$\mathfrak{so}(mn)\supset \mathfrak{so}(m)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(n)$
for general $m$ and $n$. Focusing on the case where $m$ and $n$ are even would also be sufficient.
Do you know any reference for the projection matrix and/or the branching rules of the representations?

Hi Vittorio Larotonda. Welcome to Phys.SE. Should $mn$ be $m+n$?

Can you provide more detail as to what you mean by "special embedding"? This is not standard terminology (that I am aware of) and in general there will be many embeddings with different branching etc.

Sure, I meant that $\mathfrak{so}(m) \oplus \mathfrak{so}(n)$ is an S-subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(mn)$.

Obviously $so(m)\oplus so(n)\subseteq so(m+n)\subseteq so(mn)$ if $m,n>1$.

The only meaning of "S-subalgebra" that I am familiar with is a subalgebra that doesn't contain any regular subalgebras. It is hard to find these in general and they aren't unique so I'm not sure it works well as a definition for your embedding. I suppose you might be looking at the subalgebra induced by the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^m \otimes \mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ but I don't know.

$\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ I mean of course
